# Android studio - switch active build variant for multi module project

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build-variant

My project have more than 20 modules. Whenever I'm switching active build variant, it does change build variant just for part of existing modules, I have to change some modules active build variant manually.
It's frustrating and time wasting issue. I'm asking for help, because I think this problem should has already been resolved somehow - if app has 100 modules, that would cost developer 2 hours to switch active build variant module by module, I believe there has to be some workaround, but I struggled to find one. Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answer - Build Variant Matrix Selector worked for me, rest of the responses inside thread does not work with Android Studio Electric Eel